# How to get color of certain point of control.background in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, controls

There's a control with a png as its background. And it may be clicked on by mouse and I wanna do sth. according to the color of the clicked point. How can I get the color? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, from the mouse click event argument e, you can get the Point with the exact co-ordinates of the click:

```
Point clickPoint = e.GetPosition(cntrlWithPNGasBackground);
```

Presumably, you can then grab the colour of the image at that position using something like:

```
System.Drawing.Image _image = cntrlWithPNGasBackground.BackgroundImage;
Bitmap _bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
Color _color = _bitmap.GetPixel(Point.x, Point.y);
```

Not the most efficient thing, but it gets the job done.

See:

- [`Bitmap.GetPixel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.getpixel.aspx)
- [`System.Drawing.Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx)
- [`System.Drawing.Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx)
- [`MouseEventArgs.GetPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs.getposition.aspx)
- [`System.Windows.Point`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point.aspx)

Comment: It's System.Window.Controls.Control but not System.Windows.Forms.Control. So there's only background but not backgroundimage

Comment: Well, how did you get the png into the control's background?